# Difference between thread.interrupt vs ExecutorService - Future.cancel()?

Tags: java

A thread can be interrupted by Thread.interrupt() if it is a java thread.

We can also create Executor Service with SingleThread and we can call Future.cancel.

Could someone explains the differences between the two?

Answer (score 0):

[Future Cancel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29)  vs [Thread Interrupt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29)

I think you are comparing Apple and Orange. Please check documentation of both.

Comment: yeah.we can do; but not sure if this is right platform for that. btw nice link :)